# How to scale Zookeeper with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am working on scaling the kafka cluster in Prod. Confluent provides easy way to add kafka brokers. However, how do I know how to scale zookeeper along with Kafka. What should be the ratio? Right now we have 5 zookeeper nodes for 5 kafka brokers. If I have 10 kafka brokers how many zookeeper nodes should be there?

Comment: Confluent just packages Apache Kafka. `kafka-server-start` is the only way to add nodes in any installation.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks but the question is not how to scale. But what is the ratio in which we scale zookeeper:kafka brokers.

Comment: I was just referring to "Confluent provides easy way to add kafka brokers"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zookeeper works as a coordination service for Apache Kafka which stores metadata of kafka cluster. Zookeeper cluster is called ensemble.

Number of servers in a zookeeper ensemble are an odd number(3,5 etc).These numbers represents, how much your cluster is fault tolerant.A three node ensemble ,you can run with one node missing.

With five node ensemble,you can run with two nodes missing and your cluster will be available.

You can add as many zookeeper servers based on how much you want system to be functional inspire of failures, however a ZooKeeper cluter of more than 7 nodes is not recommended for issues with overhead of latency and over-communication between those nodes.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. What is the recommended ratio of zookeeper:Kafka brokers.

Comment: It is based upon the system availability issue like i have two kafka brokers but I want them to be highly fault tolerant so I can use zookeeper 3,5,7,9,11 . There is no need to maintain any zookeeper:kafka ratio.It is totally about making the system fault tolerant.

Comment: That's correct. How do I know the capacity. Because the no of zookeepers will be based on the capacity of zookeepers to handle the kafka cluster. For instance, one Kafka broker can handle upto 4000 partitions. Similarly, I am trying to find out a group of zookeeper clusters can handle how many kafka brokers. We can lets say choose 11 Zookeeper and 50 Kafka brokers. The system is still highly available but can it be efficient.

Comment: there is no such formula for zookeeper:ratio calculation.https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/35287/how-to-decide-how-many-zookeepers-should-i-have.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880362/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-zookeeper-servers-i-need-for-a-cluster

Comment: Thanks Rohit, this helps.

Comment: A rule of thumb: smaller clusters have 3 Zookeeper nodes. Larger, production deployments typically have 5. It's very rare to see 7+ Zookeeper nodes.